# Vimeo embed CSS: override default text styles?

Tags: css, iframe, media-queries, embed, vimeo

I'm embedding a Vimeo video with a particularly long title on a responsive site, and I'm wondering if it's at all possible to override the Vimeo player's CSS with my own to control font-size, most importantly. The player embed options on Vimeo do not seem to allow for these sorts of adjustments. Using Firebug to inspect the actual embed code, I tried using variants of the following CSS to override the default player font style within a media query, but to no avail:

```
iframe #player .controls-wrapper .title h1 {
    font-size: 12px !important;
}
```

I'm assuming I'm unable to override the CSS because the embedded iframe's stylesheet must take precedence (?) I'm frankly surprised that the text-size doesn't seem to be responsive by default. Any ideas for a solution are much appreciated.

Comment: Correct, you can not alter css/styling of an iframe. In doing some googling, looks like you would have to use a custom vimeo embed player to customize an attribute like font size. Here is also a related thread. https://vimeo.com/forums/help/topic:116754

Comment: Ah ok, interesting-- thanks Alex.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to change it using jQuery. Give this  a shot:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('iframe').contents().find('#player .controls-wrapper .title h1').css({'font-size':'12px'});
});
```